# Ubuntu 14.04 crashing when 2 monitors are plugged in

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor, freeze, crash

Ubuntu 14.04 is crashing, but only if 2 monitors are plugged in.  If I start my computer with just the main monitor everything works fine.

What is weird is that yesterday everything was working normally.  I installed updates using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and that was the only thing that would have changed.

Now today when I started my computer, after I logged in the entire system froze.  Even trying `CTRL+ALT+F2` did not drop me into a shell.

What can I do to get this fixed?  I don't have a graphics card, and I have reinstalled `unity` and `ubuntu-desktop` without any luck.